# Flutter - How to migrate to null safety from very old project which was created with dart 2.10.0

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have old flutter project which was created with Dart 2.10.0 and non null safety. Now current dart version is 3.0.0.

> "dart migrate" command is no longer exists.

How to migrate to null safety ?

Comment: If you want to use the `dart migrate` too, you will need to downgrade to the last version of Flutter that uses Dart 2.x, which is Flutter 3.7.12 which uses Dart 2.19.6.  Alternatively bite the bullet and run `flutter analyze` and just fix all of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal of your project and run the following commands:

```
flutter upgrade
flutter pub upgrade --null-safety
```

After this, update the dependencies:

```
flutter pub get
```

Finally, migrate the dart code.

```
dart migrate
```

Now you have to perform the following changes as well, manually:

1. Update variable declarations, function parameters, and return types to use null safety syntax. For example, replace String with String?, and int with int?.
2. Update your code to handle nullable variables properly. Use null-aware operators like ?. and ?? to safely handle null values.
3. Use the late keyword for variables that are initialized later but guaranteed to be non-null before being accessed.
4. Make sure your widget tree, including parameters, returns, and state, is null-safe. Update constructors and calls to widgets accordingly.